# Socket programming via two network interface simuntaneoulsy

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

I want to have two tcp connection in a single machine via socket programming, But this two connection should connect to two different network interfaces. One is say my 3g dongle and the other is wifi modem. But is it possible for a single machine(OS) to have two connection active at a time? If possible how to program the tcp connection via socket programming?

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be done, if you just create two programs and run each of them, they will both be able to communicate over their respective network. When you run a program, the operating system creates a process dedicated to running that program, which is assigned time on the CPU by the scheduling algorithm in the OS. So long as your CPU can keep up with any processing associated with the networks, they will both be able to run simultaneously.

You make no mention of your plans for this, but be aware that I/O times can also limit your speeds. If you're using an older computer, it may not be able to transmit a lot of data very quickly due to an out-dated (or just low powered) network card.

Next time try to research your question first, information about this can be found with relative ease using any popular search engine, including the search bar at the top of this page. Also read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555375), or one of the other several help articles about asking questions well, that are available from the page you had to go through before asking the question.